# MySQL time clock calculations. Adjusting user error

Tags: mysql

I have just finished creating an app that tracks user tasks. A technician goes out in the field and throughout the day he or she switches between tasks.

**tbl_user_time_log**

[image: tbl_user_time_log]

These tasks are time stamped so that we can calculate time differences between the previous and the latest time stamp.

**SELECT query** to get total duration for each task.

[image: select.durations]

```
SELECT A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID,
       A.PROJECT_ID,
       A.CLIENT_ID,
       A.USER_ID,
       A.UTL_DTSTAMP,
       A.UTL_LATITUDE,
       A.UTL_LONGITUDE,
       A.UTL_EVENT,
       A.UTL_TASK,
       A.UTL_DESCRIPTION,
       /* DURATION in seconds  */
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, A.UTL_DTSTAMP, B.UTL_DTSTAMP) AS UTL_DURATION
FROM   tbl_user_time_log A
       INNER JOIN tbl_user_time_log B
               ON B.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID = ( A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID + 1 )
WHERE  A.USER_ID = '465605'
       AND DATE(A.UTL_DTSTAMP) = CURDATE()
       AND A.UTL_EVENT <> 'CLOCK OUT'
ORDER  BY A.UTL_DTSTAMP DESC;
```

**Question:**

The app works but after much research I cannot find a way to FIX time. **Since the calculation for durations rely on the previous stamp**, what happens when for example TRAVEL needs to be adjusted to a bigger time span that originally recorded? It would then overlap MONITOR and so on potentially causing a big discrepancy.

Any suggestions on how to approach the logic to solve this challenge would be greatly appreciated.

I do have the luxury of a complete logic (table & query) redesign if that's most ideal.

Comment: Put [date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), with the correct timezone, at the top of your PHP page before any inserting is done.

Comment: Pure SQL here just for clarity. PHP tag added in the event this can actually be solved in PHP. :)

Comment: @ASPiRE then you should not have tagged the question with php. I removed the tag based on your comment.

Comment: Since you only have one timestamp (no start/end) adjusting a timestamp should automatically make one duration longer and the next shorter (or vice versa) unless it is adjusted to be later than the next timestamp in the table...

Comment: Good point. It appears I may need to go for `UTL_DTSTAMP_FROM` and `UTL_DTSTAMP_TO`. On insertion of new record, the new time stamp gets added to `UTL_DTSTAMP_TO` of the previous record(current at the moment) by user id AND to `UTL_DTSTAMP_FROM` for the new record being created by this same user id. Do you believe this would allow the fixing of time to move back and forward in time without disturbing other entries as a result?

Comment: Nope, it would not. If you have to adjust an time entry in a series of time events after the creation of the series, then you have to consider the chain effect: if a past event lasted 1 hour longer than then we thought, we may have to push all subsequent events by one hour.